# How to send/receive messages through a web socket on windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, websocket, windows-phone-8.1

I have managed to establish a connection. But I want to send data in the form of json string through web socket and get response data.

send data must be in the following format.
{"seat":"E1","doj":"2015-06-13","isRtc":false,"routeId":4851114}

I am able to connect and send the data . but there is no response data. As soon data is sent, immediately connection will be disconnected. I have followed the link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh994397.aspx

**EDIT**

Comment: Please provide the code that you have tried

Comment: I have followed the link - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh994396.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you can install nuget package for json .
here you can download [newtonsoft.json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/)

You can download source code from [here](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)